# Is there a way to cache when using html canvas to draw 20000 same circles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In chrome, using html canvas to draw 20000 moving circles at the same time will cause non-fluency. However, drawing 20000 moving rectangles is fluent. I think it's because that getting the points of circles to draw is time-consuming.

And my questions is as follows:

1. Why doesn't chrome cache the points of one circle, so that it can calculate once and use the result to draw the 19999 circles left?
2. Is there a way to make it by using JavaScript?

Comment: here's is a very simple idea/reflexion: what about creating a image out of your circle, then draw that static image on the canvas instead of the circle. I mean: 1) draw a circle on canvas TMP, 2) convert canvas TMP to image IMG, 3) draw image IMG 2000 times on canvas FINAL. I think drawing image might be faster that drawing the circle, but this need to be checked ;)

Comment: I need to zoom. so if I use a image of circle, when zooming in, the image of circle maybe become mosaic.

Comment: What is the user supposed to do with 20000 circles? How will the user interact with them?

Comment: You can't show 20000 circles at once. By selecting the ones that needs drawing, draw a point (fillRect(,,1,1)) for too small circles, and such, performances should be ok.